# Install a local build with NPM 8

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm switching from Node 14 (with NPM 6) to Node 16 (with NPM 8) for my angular application.

This application has a project that we package as an NPM package.
When working locally, we have a script that will build this project (locally into the `dist/my-private-package-name` folder), and then we install this locally built pkg with `npm install dist/my-private-package-name`.

On NPM 6, we don't have to log in to install this local pkg (duh, it's a local build).
 However when I try running the above install command (in VSCode) in NPM 8, it asks me to login to GitHub, which is dumb, because it's local. I don't even have a user on GitHub because my company doesn't use that, we store our private NPM packages to a private repo.
Even when I run that command outside VSCode in the terminal, it still fails with this message:

```
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/dist/my-private-package-name.git
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/cn188854/.npm/_logs/2023-07-06T01_30_36_497Z-debug.log
```

**Surely there has to be a way to install local builds in NPM 8, right?**

If it matters, our package is scoped.

Comment: @vighnesh153 `npm install ./dist/my-private-package-name` worked! Surprised my original install command worked at all, even in NPM 6. I also found that `npm install @my-scope/my-private-package-name@file:dist/my-private-package-name` worked, but your install command looks cleaner. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: @vighnesh153 Can you post that as an answer? Comments are only temporary and I think this would be useful for future visitors. I'll happily upvote as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be searching for the package on GitHub instead of your local directory.

Prefixing it with `./` to make it a relative path might help.

```bash
npm install ./dist/my-private-package-name
```